# How to play .ogg files using xcode

Tags: xcode, audio

I want to play 3 different file formats .mp3, .wav, .ogg. I used AVAudioPlayer and managed to play mp3 and wav files but it isn't playing .ogg files. How to add .ogg support for my Xcode project.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIR, it's not directly supported by the frameworks, but the format/standard is open, and multiple open readers exist. It's a container so... you decide the level of support you need.